# Can you force ImageMagick to use PNG-8 alpha transparency?

Tags: optimization, png, imagemagick

When I try to run a bunch of PNG-8 images with alpha transparency through Imagemagick, it converts them to PNG-32, increasing the file size a lot.

Is it possible to force Imagemagick to keep my image type as 8-bit PNG?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
convert test.png PNG8:test2.png
```

I've had varying luck with IM and PNG8, but this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: How do we use this ? Can you share any example

Comment: That *is* an example. What are you looking for?

Comment: Keep the format list under your pillow: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: so if I use convert test.png PNG24:test2.png can it convert an image with bit depth of 32 to 24?

Comment: It seems that this method destroys any partial transparency in the image, even though the PNG format supports colormapped images with semitransparent colors. The only way I know of to preserve such partial transparency, while still obtaining 8-bit colormapped output, is to tell ImageMagick to output PNG32 images and [re-quantize them with pngquant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032098).

Answer (score 10):

I seem to get the best result using the following

```
convert src.png -colors 256 PNG8:dest.png
```

Comment: To go from a B&W PNG to an 8-bit color PNG, `-colors 256` is what worked for me on ImageMagick 6.8.7-7

Comment: This may be the best option if you have more than 256 colours in there, as it will do a proper reduction. The answer without -colors doesn't do this.

Comment: `-depth 8` produces the best result on ImageMagick 7. Both `-colors 255` and `PNG8:` results has too much artifacts.