# Convert PNG images to bit-depth 8 bit (Node)

Tags: node.js, image

Is there any way to convert a PNG file to 8 bit-depth?

I've tried the following, with some variations (With GraphicsMagic module, gm):

```js
gm(`${IMAGE_PROCESSING_SD}images_thumbs_sd_${i + 1}.png`)
      .bitdepth(8)
      .write(`${IMAGE_PROCESSING_SD}images_thumbs_sd_${i + 1}.png`, () => {
        console.log('finished 8 bit conversion');
      });
```

But it keeps having 32 bit-depth on some images, 24 in others. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but can still help some people.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032098/10473393), i've used `convert` (method 4 from answer) to do the work.

I've installed `shelljs` to aid me with this.

So basically, the solution was something like this:

```js
const shell = require('shelljs');

shell.exec(`convert "${path}" "PNG8:${path}"`);
```

(To use this, the user needs imagemagick to be installed)

Hope it helps someone in trouble.