# Alpha channel in IE 6.x

Tags: internet-explorer, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get PNG transparency working in browsers that don't natively support it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243/how-to-get-png-transparency-working-in-browsers-that-dont-natively-support-it)

How do I get IE 6.x to display png files correctly?

I have a designer insisting on drop shadows over a background pattern, and customers who for some reason insist on using IE 6.x

Comment: would you be so nice and give any answer a solution-flag??!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to search google for "png hack" ... brings up [this](http://www.mongus.net/pngInfo/) and [this](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/pngbehavior/pngbehavior.html)

edit:
somehow a dublicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243/how-to-get-png-transparency-working-in-browsers-that-dont-natively-support-it)

Answer (score 0):

Does your designer absolutely insist on the drop shadows being there in IE6? A browser thats market share is diminishing everyday. Or will he be happy that the majority of users that are using a more modern browser will see the shadows.

This could be technical decision, based on your sites current and projected statistics for IE 6 usage, vs the cost of implementing these drop-shadows. But don't be afraid to argue it from a technical cost/benefit perspective, and the fact that not all browsers need to render your site identically.

Comment: As of this comment's writing, IE6 still has significant (>20%) market share by any metric you use (Alexa, Google, whatever).  If your website is "firefoxlovers.com" then maybe this advice is applicable, but otherwise ignoring IE6 users would be an absolutely terrible business decision.

Comment: Not having drop-shadows in IE6 would be a terrible business decision?

Who said anything about ignoring IE6? I'm talking about making a cost/benefit analysis of whether the extra effort of implementing the drop-shadows in IE6 is worthwhile. In some cases perhaps it is, but doing the analysis is still worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AlphaImageLoader either directly or through many scripts that wrap over it. Personally i recommend [IE7](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) because it solves a lot of other IE6 problems, not just alpha transparency.

Also, with some layouts, it might be possible to go without transparency at all and still have it look like your designer wants. I don't know what does it looks like, so i can't say for sure though.