# How to fix "png opacity" and still support positioning at the same time?

Tags: css, png, background-color

[alt text http://maishudi.com/icons_ns6.png](http://maishudi.com/icons_ns6.png)

How to correct it so that it's always like,like in firefox?

**EDIT**:

I tried some fix,but not working for me,

I'm using something like below in my application:

```
background:transparent url(../static/icons_ns6.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -80px;
```

Say,I need to position the background image.

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: by the way - works fine for me on both FF 3 and IE7
if it is IE6, then IE6 has this transparency problem

Answer (score 0):

IE is known for its problems with transparency in PNGs. There were many topics here regarding that: check for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243/how-to-get-png-transparency-working-in-browsers-that-dont-natively-support-it).

Comment: The url in the post marked as answer has been obsolete.Is there another one?

Answer (score 0):

The [iepngfix.htc available here](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) supports background positioning.  And even makes PNG transparency work in IE5.5!

Answer (score 0):

This was useful for me: [CSS Opacity in Internet Explorer (IE)](http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/archives/2006/08/16/css-opacity-in-internet-explorer-ie/)

Note the quirks and use use of the CSS "zoom" attribute. YMMV.